# Why is FlexMojos "unable to resolve 'assets/**/*.png' for transcoding"?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flexmojos

I'm trying to mavenize a Flex project using Flash Builder 4 as IDE.
I'm using flexmojos `4.0-beta-7` with flex sdk `4.5.0.19786`.

In my `pom.xml` I have:

```
<build>
   <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/flex</sourceDirectory>
   ...
</build>
```

and I have this directory structure `${basedir}/src/main/flex/assets/icons/**.png`.

I have `${basedir}/pom.xml`. I followed [OpenScales fx samples](https://bitbucket.org/gis/openscales/src/a137a922ecc0/openscales-fx-examples/src/main/flex/) as a model for my project.

FlashBuilder compiles normally, but invoking `$>mvn clean package` lots of `unable to resolve 'assets/icons/*.png' for transcoding` errors are raised.

Does `assets` folder have to be added explicitly for compiling? How?

[Here it is my complete `${basedir}/pom.xml`](http://pastie.org/2279409) and [here the output from `$>mvn clean package`](http://pastie.org/2279400).

Comment: Please draw your directory structure more clearly. I mean where are assets are located.

Comment: @Constantiner Done. Hope is more clear now. Plese let me know.

Comment: In your error message I can find `'assets/icons/*.png'`. Can't understand where Maven got this string. Is it in your POM? Please publish reference to the `'assets/icons/*.png'` from your POM or your code. Maybe it is better to publish all your POM?

Comment: @Constantiner Pasties for pom.xml and mvn command output added.

Comment: Ok. Issue is clear now. Did you tried to use `'/assets/icons/food_fr.gif'` instead of `'assets/icons/food_fr.gif'`?

Comment: @Constantiner What do you mean exactly? I have used explicitly no assets icon path, with or without '/'. I only set my <sourceDirectory> in the pom.xml. I thought this was enough for correct compiling... Do you any magic recipe for me? :)

Comment: @Constantiner let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1877/discussion-between-giorgio-vespucci-and-constantiner)

Comment: I had this very error because of a typo in the file name.  If you see this error "unable to resolve asset", make sure the pathname is correct.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem a long time ago. And solved it replacing all the paths in `Embed` directives from `'assets/icons/food_fr.gif'` to `'/assets/icons/food_fr.gif'`.

Comment: Perfect! :) Apparently FlashBuilder resolves the assets paths with or without the initial slash. Maven is a little bit exigent ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally I find this post, otherwise I would not trust it can work any more - -

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736297/get-error-unable-to-resolve-assets-images-png-for-transcoding-while-bui I had to apply both solutions

Comment: Documentation here http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_3.html

Comment: "/" prefix also brought a solution for Ant script with same kind of error message.